# Linq Paging - How to incorporate total record count

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to figure out the best way of getting the record count will incorporating paging.  I need this value to figure out the total page count given a page size and a few other variables.
This is what i have so far which takes in the starting row and the page size using the skip and take statements.

```
promotionInfo = (from p in matches
orderby p.PROMOTION_NM descending
select p).Skip(startRow).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

I know i could run another query, but figured there may be another way of achieving this count without having to run the query twice.

Thanks in advance,
Billy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know i could run another query, but figured there may be another way of achieving this count without having to run the query twice.

No, you have to run the query.

You can do something like:

```
var source = from p in matches
             orderby p.PROMOTION_NM descending
             select p;
var count = source.Count();
var promotionInfo = source.Skip(startRow).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Be advised, however, that [`Skip(0)` isn't free](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/06/10/38313/).

Comment: This is exactly how i wrote it knowing that this is two hits.  

By skip(0) isn't free you mean resource intense?  Should just be removed if startRow is 0?

Comment: Yews, just get rid of it then. Click the link for more info.

Comment: do you know if the "charge" for Skip(0) has been refunded in EF 4?

Comment: @John, it hasn't been changed, but L2S has been changed to work like L2E. See Damien Guard's comment on my blog. It's apparently a QA feature since many people don't bothe to test past page 1.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've been looking at what's generated from EF courtesy of the SQL profiler, so I'll fiddle around with some generic paging optimizations.

Comment: Minor point - wouldn't it make more sense to move the OrderByDescending to the last line, given that you don't care about ordering for the count?